# Server Client communication fails at Outputstreams

Tags: java, client, client-server, server, outputstream

**My program is basically:**

1. Client sends a String to Server,
2. Based on this String, Server is creating an ArrayList,
3. ArrayList is sent back to the Client.

**What is failing here is:**

After Client sends a String, the Server receives it and doesn't do anything else. In this time Client keeps on working and gets a NullPointer.

**Client side:**

```
    public static ArrayList<String> sendStringToServer(String report) {

    Socket socket;

    ArrayList<String> fieldsList = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {

        socket = new Socket("localhost", 2345);

        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(os, true);

        ps.println(report);
        ps.flush();

        //Here the debugger should stop and wait for server to create a List

        //at this point there is no answer, code breaks
        ObjectInputStream objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        Object object = objectInput.readObject();
        fieldsList = (ArrayList<String>) object;

        socket.close();

        return fieldsList;

    } catch (IOException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

**Server side:**

```
public class Server {

private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private Socket clientSocket;
private String telegram;
private StringBuilder telegramSB;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JRException {

    new Server();
}
public Server() {

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2345);

        while (true) {

            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

            try {

                //debugger goes to here and then stops
                telegram = br.readLine();

                int counter = 0;

                boolean startSeq = false;

                for (char ch : telegram.toCharArray()) {

                    if (counter == 0 && ch == '/') {

                        startSeq = true;
                    }

                    if (startSeq == true) {

                        telegramSB = new StringBuilder();
                        telegramSB.append(ch);
                    }

                    if (ch == '\n') {

                        if (telegram.length() < 255) {

                            sendListWithFields();

                        } else {

                            new Launcher(telegram).run();
                        }
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
            } catch (JRException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you send end of line (EOF) character/s?

Comment: @eyp yes, i do but my program never gets there. It reads the bufferedReader and then stops.

Answer (score 0):

My guess here would be that the BufferedReader is waiting to fill its buffer and you haven't sent enough data for it to do that and return so its waiting for more data to come through that never does (because your clients stops writing and starts to read).  You could test this theory temporarily by dumping a load more data into the OutputStream on the client and flushing it.

If the above is the case then you probably want to not use BufferedReader but you have other issues here which also mean you probably want to avoid using PrintStream and BufferedReader for communication and serialisation anyway.  For example the default character encoding on two different machines and JVMs could be different.  When you create your PrintStream and InputStreamReader you don't specify a character encoding so they could end up being mismatched and the string that you write (including the newline character) could end up being understood completely differently by the remote side, this could also be a reason why its blocking (the client side encodes the newline character in one way but the server is expecting it to be encoded a completely different way), though less likely I think .

If you don't *have* to use PrintStream then I would suggest instead using DataOutputStream / DataInputStream:

```
//Client
BufferedOutputStream bufout = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(bufout);
dout.writeUTF(report);
dout.flush();

//Server
BufferedInputStream bufin = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(bufin);
String report = din.readUTF();
```

You still get buffering from the BufferedIn/OutputStreams so it will be performant but the DataIn/OutputStreams will manage termination of variable length objects for you - they will send a length prefixing the string to tell the other side exactly how many bytes to read, so you don't need to use a special character to terminate the string you wrote, and this also means it doesn't matter what the content of your String is.  In your example above even if it was working if your String had a newline character in it the server would read up until that first newline character, not to the end of the string you sent and that would put them out of sync for the next send/receive along that stream.

Using write/readUTF also specifies an encoding (UTF-8) so there is no mismatch there either.